# is VS 11 Ultimate version released?

Tags: visual-studio

what is the latest version in micro soft VS, is that VS 11 ultimate version is released or only beta version is released

Answer (score 2):

Vs 11 was renamed to vs 2012 and currently releasesd as a release candidate. I would expect a final rev by the fall.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 Beta was released on February 1, 2012 and can be downloaded from the [product's home page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us). The Release Candidate was released on May 31, 2012.

Comment: can you please tell me is there any version called VS 2011 released by Microsoft.

Comment: There was never a "VS2011". "VS11" was the code name for Visual Studio 2012, which is version 11 of the product.